# Oracle update identic rows in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, odp.net

I have a table called users with following columns :

```
Name, Location, Active (all varchars).
John    Berlin  OK
Danny   London  OK
Robert  NY      OK
John    Berlin  OK
Danny   Berlin  OK
```

I would like to update the Active column to NOK for users that appear more than once (two, three or x times) - and they have the same name and location (identical rows in the table) Like this :

```
    John    Berlin  NOK
    Danny   London  OK
    Robert  NY      OK
    John    Berlin  NOK
    Danny   Berlin  OK
```

How can i do this ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, you could use:

```
UPDATE your_table
   SET active = 'NOK'
 WHERE (name, location) IN (SELECT name, location 
                              FROM your_table 
                             GROUP BY name, location 
                            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do it like this:

Insert duplicate values into a #temp table

```
select t.Name, t.Location
into #test
from tablename t
group by t.Name, t.Location
having count(t.Name) > 1
```

Make the update

```
update tablename
set Active = 'NOK'
from tablename t
inner join #test t2 on t.Name = t2.Name and t.Location = t2.Location
```

---

Or in one step:

```
update tablename
set Active = 'NOK'
from tablename t
inner join (select t.Name, t.Location
            from tablename t
            group by t.Name, t.Location
            having count(t.Name) > 1) t2 on t.Name = t2.Name and t.Location = t2.Location
```